# SQL - IF a value equals a certain number then the amount of rows should equal that certain number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Scenario: I have 1 columns in my select statement; Name which I want to repeat based on the value of a calculated field named Number calculated using a case statement like this 
 
Case when number<0.95 then 0 
 when number>=1 then 10.... END AS Number.
 
 Example Jim W has a Number value of 6 so I want the SQL statement to return 6 rows with the Name of Jim W.

Name 
JIM W 
JIM W
JIM W
JIM W
JIM W
JIM W

Other points to note is that it should group by a column named region and its SQL Server 2008.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

The easiest way to do this in sql server is to join with the system table  master..spt_values
provided your number of repetition for each name should be less than 2048

```
select T.Name from test12 T join master..spt_values M
on T.number>M.number
where type='p'
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/023be/1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My only issue is that my 'Number' is based on a calculation using a Case statement e.g Case When Number<0.95 then 0 When Number >=1 then 10 .... END AS Number